# MYSQL select table rows where column contains same data in more than one record in my code

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql code here -

```
$querymypm = "SELECT * FROM pm WHERE recieverun='$uname' AND senderun='$c' ORDER BY pmid DESC";
```

But I want it like this -

```
$querymypm = "SELECT * FROM pm WHERE recieverun='///(Taking more than one value)///' AND senderun='///(Taking more than one value)///' ORDER BY pmid DESC";
```

Comment: Can you please ask it clearly, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` operator.

```
$querymypm = "SELECT * FROM pm WHERE recieverun IN ('$uname1', '$uname2', '$uname3') AND senderun IN ('$c1', '$c2', '$c3') ORDER BY pmid DESC";
```